# How do you properly deploy Angular application?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

I'm writing an angular2 application, and want to deploy it on an EC2 instance. This is how I've currently set it up.

- Used `gulp` on the server to build typescript and scss.
- Then I setup nginx to setup a simple HTTP server to serve the files directly.

This is my nginx conf at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
    access_log off;
    root /home/ubuntu/www/flowchart-wizard/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.html;
    }

    location /* {
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

After I added the rule for `/*`, everything so far is working well (including routing). Being a very beginner at this, I'm not sure how good of a setup this is.

I also tried running a `lite-server` in background with `nohup` and directed requests in nginx using `proxy_pass`. However I quickly dropped the idea because `lite-server` is meant for development only.

What is your method? Will I face any issues later on with my current setup? What is the best way of deploying an angular2 app?